# win32gui module not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, win32gui

the module installation was successful and worked from the Powershell though It's giving a 'Module not found error' on importing it in the file.
Its installed inside Virtualenv.
Screenshot provided herewith.

Screenshot
[image]

**EDIT:** Somehow solved the problem, Not sure how it worked

1. Installed win32gui from a [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/).
2. Inside virtualenv Installed win32gui from pip(non cached) from
   **admin PowerShell** `pip --no-cache-dir install pywin32`
3. to use pywin32 for "system-wide" features `python
   Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

and now it worked!

Comment: Well for guys who came here, I don't know why it works, but try `pip install pypiwin32` in my case. I know it looks irrelevant, but nothing to lose guys, good luck!